# SQLite: Query next record after matching consecutive rows from criteria

Tags: sql, sqlite

Let’s say I have a sql table that has 2 columns: the first column contains the ‘primary key’ and the second column contain an ‘Integer’ from 0 to 100.

Question 1a: Is there a way to search for 3 or more consecutive rows matching a given value (eg. 3, 29, 88)

Question 1b: Is there a way to get the next value(record) that comes after the 3 or more records in a consecutive order.

Question 1c: if the database contains more then 1 match of the consecutive order show all next value(record) of the consecutive order in descending order of ‘primary key’

I have little to basic knowledge of SQL statements and I would appreciate if someone can point me in right direction or provide an example on how to achieve this.

---

EDIT 20-9-2018

Thank you for taking the time to answer my question.
@MikeT: Your example is little bit beyond my knowledge of SQL but going thru you walkthrough and looking some of the commands I understand what it does (I think). But it isn’t exactly what I am looking for, although its little bit difficult to verify for me since the values are created random on every run.

So like @D-Shih asked here is an example of what I am trying to achieve:
[Image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nYWMN.png)

Comment: Could your provide some sample data and expect result?

Answer (score 0):

> Question 1a: Is there a way to search for 3 or more consecutive rows
>   matching a given value (eg. 3, 29, 88)

I believe the following shows an example :-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS xtable;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS xtable (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, myint INTEGER);
WITH RECURSIVE cte1 AS (SELECT abs(random()) % 101
        UNION ALL SELECT abs(random()) % 101 FROM cte1 LIMIT 500)
INSERT INTO xtable (myint) SELECT * FROM cte1; 
-- RESULT 1
SELECT * FROM xtable ORDER BY myint;
-- RESULT 2
SELECT * FROM xtable WHERE myint IN (3,29,88,99,100,77,52,21) GROUP BY myint HAVING count(myint) >= 3 ORDER BY id;
```

- Note this populates the xtable with 500 rows with random numbers from 0-100 in the **myint** column which equates to your second column. As such the results vary each time it is run.
- **3,29,88,99,100,77,52,21** is your list of given values (extra numbers added to get more hits).
- `WHERE myint IN(....)` will restrict the rows selected to only those in the list.
- `GROUP BY myint` effectively creates 1 row for each unique value in the **myint** column, thus allowing the use of aggregate functions such as **count**. [SQL As Understood By SQLite - Aggregate Functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html)
- `HAVING` is a sort of after the fact WHERE so `HAVING count(myint) >= 3` restricts the rows output to those that have a count of 3 or more.
- `ORDER BY id`, may or may not be required but may be suitable for the subsequent questions.

A result from the above could be :-

[image]

> Question 1b: Is there a way to get the next value(record) that comes
>   after the 3 or more records in a consecutive order.

If you mean that the next value is the next primary key, then if the primary key is an integer **and** it's an alias of the **rowid** and there have been no deletions, failed updates (creating a temp table could overcome these limitations) then the following may suffice :-

```
WITH cte1 AS (SELECT *, max(id) AS maxid FROM xtable WHERE myint IN (3,29,88,99,100,77,52,21) GROUP BY myint HAVING count(myint) >= 3 ORDER BY id DESC)
SELECT * FROM  xtable, cte1 WHERE maxid + 1 = xtable.id ORDER BY xtable.id;
;
```

- This uses the first query to ascertain the 3 or more consecutive rows (as a Common Table Expression), takes it's primary and adds 1 to then select the row with the next primary key.

This for example would result in :-

[image]

based upon (row with primary key as 359) as per :-

[image]

> Question 1c: if the database contains more then 1 match of the
>   consecutive order show all next value(record) of the consecutive order
>   in descending order of ‘primary key’

This might be what you are asking for (basically the above but for > 1 consecutive numbers and ordered by the primary key in descending order)

```
WITH cte1 AS (SELECT *, max(id) AS maxid FROM xtable WHERE myint IN (3,29,88,99,100,77,52,21) GROUP BY myint HAVING count(myint) > 1 ORDER BY id DESC)
SELECT * FROM  xtable, cte1 WHERE maxid + 1 = xtable.id ORDER BY xtable.id DESC;
;
```

Although you could mean :-

```
WITH cte1 AS (SELECT *, max(id) AS maxid FROM xtable WHERE myint IN (3,29,88,99,100,77,52,21) GROUP BY myint HAVING count(myint) > 1 ORDER BY id DESC)
SELECT * FROM  xtable, cte1 WHERE maxid - 1 = xtable.id ORDER BY xtable.id DESC;
;
```

- Note again this is based upon consecutive numbering of the primary key.